# Direct input into 3rd party terminal

Tags: javascript, python, terminal

I am searching for solution to be able to input text into console running simple app with python or other language. I have solution in python to activate window and send keystrokes into cmd or store value in clipboard and paste it into cmd. Have also similar solution with auto-hotkey. But problem is I want to be able to send commands very fast to multiple 5-10 cmd.

I found solution that with [Hyper](https://hyper.is/store/hyper-broadcast) I can broadcast from one terminal into multiple. But i need 100% reliable and fast way to directly communicate with terminal.

Comment: Can you explain, why you need to communicate with terminals ?

Comment: It's 3rd party trading terminal that is running in terminal. If u want to manage multiple api connections at same time u make multiple copies of this app and run it multiple times with different config files for connection. So what I want to achieve is to be able to input at same time with 100% reliability input into those terminals.

Comment: I have solution in Autohotkey and Python that is activating window storing my command in clipboard and pasting very fast into all terminals. But i wonder if i can just somehow connect into multiple cmds or 3rd party solutions terminals and send data directly not withe keystrokes or copy paste